# Disassociate Ant with Android XML Files

Tags: android, ant

My XML files are showing the ANT icon in my eclipse and not allowing me to build as layout files for an Android project.  Any idea how to disassociate my Android XML files from ANT?

For example...when I create an "appwidget-provider" from the menu options and am left with the start and end tag to build my file I get this error from this stub:

Unexpected element "{}appwidget-provider" 
 {antlib:org.apache.tools.ant}appwidget-provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



</appwidget-provider>
```

Strange thing is that I can create this file outside of Eclipse, for example in Notepad and then save it to my project in the appropriate folder and it will open fine in Eclipse this way with no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File associations are in Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations (on a Mac, Preferences is under the Eclipse menu. Not sure where it is on Windows or Linux).

Most likely you have a *.xml in there only associated with Ant Editor or Ant Editor is set as the default.

Comment: On work on both Mac and PC...on a PC it is under the "Window" menu.   Thanks!